# New Instagram API PHP

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

**1)** Regarding the new Instagram API, is there another way, than curl, but still in PHP to post a photo (like Facebook API)?

```
// (For example) :
// Possibility to install Instagram SDK with composer ? And then:

use Instagram\Instagram;

$ insta = new Instagram ([
                 'app_id' => '',
                 'app_secret' => '',
                 'default_graph_version' => '',
                 ]);

$ response = $ insta-> post ('/where', $ data, 'token');

// Like Facebook, you see :-)
```

**2)** Is it necessary to need ALL these 3 permissions : manage_pages, instagram_basic and Instagram Public Content Access?

Comment: "is there another way, than curl"...well you could use a different HTTP client library. But you still have to make a HTTP request to use the API, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Yes You Can :-) see the doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing#publish-photos apparently there is no other way to post photos :-(

Comment: @heyselecta Read the limitations at the top: “Can only be used by Instagram Business IG Users. Cannot be used to publish content on Instagram Creator IG Users.” It’s just for creating adverts.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Yes I have read. The Instagram account is precisely an Instagram Business IG User, not a personal or Instagram Creator IG Users.

Comment: do you have any composer instagram that be able to upload photo and make your code works?